# Deploying to DigitalOcean using github/action-doctl@v2 with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, github, docker-compose, github-actions, digital-ocean

I’ve a docker-compose.yml containing frontend, admin_frontend, backend, nginx images. I'd like to achieve that whenever I push to my github master branch then automatically build all the docker images defined in my docker-compose (as I have same settings etc. in there) file. After that push the images to my DigitalOcean Container Registry - so finally I can run the fresh deployed app on my droplet.

It's a part from my workflow file - but it seems like it doesn't build/(or push) the images from my docker-compose.

```
name: deploy app to digital ocean droplet

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  main-fe_build:
  admin-fe_build:
  main-be_build:
  main-fe_test:
  build_and_push:
    name: Build & Push
    needs: main-fe_test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Create env file
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo "${{ secrets.SERVER_ENV_PROD }}" > .env
          cat .env
          
      - name: Build image
        run: docker compose -f docker-compose.yml build
        
      - name: Install doctl
        uses: digitalocean/action-doctl@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          
      - name: Log in to DO Container Registry
        run: doctl registry login --expiry-seconds 600
        
      - name: Push image to DO Container Registry
        run: docker compose -f docker-compose.yml push
        
      - name: Deploy Stack
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSHKEY }}
          port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
          script: |
            cd /root/apps/myapp
            ls
```

Attached a screenshot about the workflow. As you see build/push images took 0s:

[image]

Comment: You are not providing any details of the registry, where you want to have an image pushed. Having `docker compose -f ..yml push` would not trigger it, you need to push an image with `docker push $IMAGENAME` This step-by-step tutorial has it pretty well outlined: https://faun.pub/full-ci-cd-with-docker-github-actions-digitalocean-droplets-container-registry-db2938db8246

Comment: As soon as I login to my DO container registry - it will be the place/information where the images will be pushed. Meanwhile I solved the problem. In my `docker-compose` file I forgot to add `build`˙so that's why it did not build the images & was build time 0s and skipped all images in the _Push images step_. Thanks anyway for help, I'll add the solution as an answer soon.

Comment: @Tivi I can push the image into DO container registry. But not able to deploy in droplet. If you solved the problem, can you please post the workflow file. Will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to have any `deploy` directive in the file. Instead of these:

```
  admin-fe_build:
  main-be_build:
  main-fe_test:
  build_and_push:
```

you would want to have a `deploy:` followed by targets…

Comment: I don't understand. The `build_and_push` job is supposed to do the deployment here. The first 4 jobs are for CI (and test) not for deploy. What `deploy:` directive should contains?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/mvkaran/openmct-tutorial/blob/completed/.github/workflows/stage.yml

Comment: I think it's something different that I'm trying to achieve. It uses DOCKERHUB and other things.